# Resultset within resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

1. I am facing a slight issue. I am getting data from a table and then
   I loop the resultset. during each loop I use the row's data returned
   by resultset to execute another query on another table. I am posting
   the code below.
2. The question is, I am sensing some problem in my code but cannot
   identify it. The code is running fine without any errors or
   exceptions. Help me to find the issue. And explain me about it too.
3. I know that we can use Dao for the first resultset. But won't it
   create too     many objects.

   ```
     public ResultSet search_NatSupport() throws ClassNotFoundException,     SQLException  {

    String query = "SELECT SYMBOL, Date, sup, res FROM Nat_Support WHERE SYMBOL IS NOT ?;";

           PreparedStatement stmt  =  null;
           ResultSet rs            =  null;
           DBHelper helper         =  DBHelper.getInstance();

           stmt = helper.getConn().prepareStatement(query);
           stmt.setString(1, null);
           rs   = stmt.executeQuery();

            return rs;
       }

      public void searchAgain(ResultSet rs) {

       String query = "select * from bhav_NSE where symbol = ?";

       PreparedStatement stmt = null;

       try {

           while (rs.next()) {

               stmt    = DBHelper.getInstance().getConn().prepareStatement(query);
               stmt.setString(1, rs.getString(1));
               ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();

               while(res.next()){
                   System.out.println(res.getString(1));
               }
               res.close();
           }
           rs.close();
       } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }



       public static void main(String[] args)   { 

       BhavMaster_NSE finals = new BhavMaster_NSE();

       try {

           finals.searchAgain(finals.search_NatSupport());

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

           // TODO Auto-generated catch block

           e.printStackTrace();

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Nothing's wrong but i doubt about my approach of using resultsets. Is it okay to use one resultset inside another looping resultset.

Comment: No it's not, you can probably use only one request (something like `SELECT * FROM bhav_NSE WHERE symbol IN (SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL FROM Nat_Support)`. Btw, you're leaking resources.

Comment: Are you pointing towards the unclosed statement and connection.

Comment: Code is tightly coupled .You can probably take out Query Part in generic method having Parameter Query String and List of Parameter

Comment: @Mureinik I can use your query but i need Symbol, date, sup and res from first query and then some column data from second query for later use.

Comment: No need For two result Set .You can join two tables on symbol key

Comment: @rupesh_padhye ok i will try joins. Thanks for the advice, it will solve the problem of two resultsets.

Comment: @rupesh_padhye could you give me a simple code example for                    **You can probably take out Query Part in generic method having Parameter Query String and List of Parameter**

Comment: You can start your own! I think it is pretty straight ..and if you face any problem stack overflow is always there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two result Set ,Join the tables on keys,(here Symbol) and combine not null in same Query

```
 public void search()
        { 
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            String query = "select bnse.* from bhav_NSE bnse,Nat_Support nsup where bnse.symbol=nsup.symbol and nsup.symbol is not null";
            stmt   = DBHelper.getInstance().getConn().prepareStatement(query);
             ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();

                while(res.next()){
                    // Get data res.getString(..);
                }
                res.close();
            }
            rs.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem once i needed to use the return result of a `resultset` as an input for other one but i found that I can't do this , After debugging i found that when you write a `Resultset` within a `Resultset` the first one became equals `Null`

So here is a Trick :

```
public void searchAgain(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
           bhavNse(rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void bhavNse(String var) {
   try {
      String query = "select * from bhav_NSE where symbol = ?";
      PreparedStatement stmt = null;
      stmt    = DBHelper.getInstance().getConn().prepareStatement(query);
      stmt.setString(1, var);
      ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
      while(res.next()){
          System.out.println(res.getString(1));
      }
      res.close();
      } 
      catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to put `;` at the end of query.
2. Use try with resource when using any `Closeable` resource

Even if you want to throw `Exception` to callee, you can do it with `throw` keyword.

```
try(Connection conn = DBHelper.getInstance().getConn()) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ...
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
    ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   // handle exception here or throw it as below :
   throw ex;
}
```

`try-with-resource` will take care of closing all the resources even any failure occur.

**OR** the old approach is to *mind closing the resources* in failure and in success too.

Comment: try-with-resource is a good option, but we are using Jdk 1.6 so we have to go via long way. I have to change the code later for compatibility, because i am using multi catch here. Which will give errors in java 6.